# notifyDataSetChanged() без перезагрузки RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Создаю  `RecyclerView` для ввода данных пользователя. У пользователя может быть несколько телефонов и емейлов, остальные данные в единственном экземляре.
Когда пользователь начинает писать телефон - в `RecyclerView` вставляется новый `ViewHolder` снизу с пустым `EditText`, если стирает телефон, то поле удаляется. Разумеется остальные поля при этом мы трогать не должны.
Я обратился к `notifyItemRemoved()` и `notifyItemInserted()` и решил задачу с телефонами, но емейл оказался орешком покрепче. Проблем была в том, что когда я вводил хотя бы один телефон и начинал вводить емейл - `ViewHolder` снизу не добавлялся. Я ломал голову, сто раз менял условия, наконец нарисовал все на бумаге, проверил сто раз - все равно не помогло, тогда я догадался вставить `Log.d` и увидел (а `TextWatcher` для поля ввода у меня назначается в `onBind()`), что не важно сколько я телефонов введу - `position` для холдера с email, который я редактирую не изменится.

То есть, имея пустую форму `position` для пустого поля телефона - 0, емейла - 1, ввожу телефоны - для телефонов `position` определяется правильно, но холдер c email продолжает иметь `position` = 1.
Стал вызывать `notifyItemRangeChanged()`, стало лучше, но иногда вылезает ошибка, что нельзя вызывать этот метод в моменты когда "RecyclerView computing or scrolling".

Каким образом правильно обрабатывать такие ситуации?
Цель, которой я хочу достигнуть, это гладкая анимация появления текстового поля на вводе емейла и телефона, без лишних мерцаний, которые дает `notifyItemRangeChanged()`. Самым подходящим способом было бы слушать анимацию `RecyclerView` и на завершении делать `notifyDataSetChanged()` и запрашивать фокус для поля ввода, но я не вижу такого рода listener'ов для `RecyclerView`.

Comment: как вы создаете ViewHolder, используюте getItemViewType?

Comment: @georgehardcore, спасибо за ответ, но уже разобрался. Да, использую view type и так как поля одинаковвые, но биндиться должны по разному, передаю его в конструктор VH, и в onBind прохожусь по viewType switch конструкцией. Проблема была в том, что в onBind надо было делать setText, и он провоцировал вызов afterTextChanged в котором я проверял, введен ли телефон или email чтобы добавить еще строку. В итоге вызов notifyDataSet уходил в рекурсию. Спасло обнуление textwatcher перед setText и возвращение его после. Немного пипец, но сейчас телефоны быстрые, поэтому все работает гладко и красиво ))

Comment: Если вы нашли решение своей проблемы самостоятельно, оформите его в виде ответа (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос"). Это поможет другим людям с аналогичной проблемой решить ее быстрее.

Answer (score -1):

Кажется я нашел решение, надо только приспособить под

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationFinished(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        updateEmptyView();
    }
});
```

Comment: Не помогло, стало чаще вылезать Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling